# ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException Error but don't know why

Tags: java, methods, instance

So i am creating a class for "MiniString" which is just full of instance methods for the object MiniString, every MiniString has an instance variable that is a char[]. When testing my methods, I can't find where I am going wrong with my substring() method. There are two substring methods where one takes a parameter of int and the other takes two int parameters. I keep getting the error on the one int parameter method. The substring method is supposed to return a new MiniString formed of the characters between the position in the target Ministring specified by the int parameter, and the end of the target MiniString. The error I keep getting in my JUnit Tester is the following:

```
java.lang.ArrayOutofBoundsException:22
at MiniString.substring(MiniString.java:141)
at MiniString.substring(MiniString.java:159)
```

Here are my constructors for the object MiniString:

```
private char[] miniscule;

 MiniString(char[] array){
  int i = 0;
  miniscule = new char[array.length];
  while (i < array.length){
   miniscule[i] = array[i];
   i++;
  }
 }
 MiniString(String string){
  int i = 0;
  miniscule = new char[string.length()];
  while (i < string.length()){
   this.miniscule[i] = string.charAt(i);
   i++;
  }
 }
```

and here is the code for the two substring() methods:

```
public MiniString substring(int start, int end){
  int i = start; 
  if (end > start){
   char[] temp = new char[end - start];
   MiniString range = new MiniString(temp);
   while (i < end){
    range.miniscule[i] = this.miniscule[i];
    i++;
   }
   return range;
  }
  else{
   char[] temp = new char[1];
   MiniString range = new MiniString(temp);
   range.miniscule[0] = 0;
   return range;
  }
 }
 public MiniString substring(int position){
  int start = position;
  int end = this.miniscule.length;
  char[] temp = new char[end - start];
  MiniString output = new MiniString(temp);

  output = substring(start, end);
  return output;
 }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use the information the exception is giving you. Which line is the exception pointing to, i.e. which line is line 22? What array access is being attempted there? Now set a breakpoint or add a println right before that line to show you the index you're trying to use and the array.length  of the array you're accessing.  If you still can't figure it out, then provide that information in your question ("... I marked line 22 where it says '// line 22 - exception throws here'.  I added a println and it showed that the index is XXX and the array length is XXX. I don't understand why ..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first `substring` method, the line

```
range.miniscule[i] = this.miniscule[i];
```

is the most likely suspect.  I expect you really want

```
range.miniscule[i - start] = this.miniscule[i];
```

`String` has substring methods that do approximately what you're doing here, but I presume you're doing this to learn, rather than reinventing string handling for a production use.

If you're using Java 6, you might also want to look at the `Arrays.copyOfRange(T[] ts, int i, int i1)` method, which does most of the work you're doing in your `substring` methods.

Comment: Happy to help.  Now as you seem to be new here, click on the checkbox to mark it as an accepted answer, and I'll be even happier!

Answer (score 0):

Don already pointed out where your problem lies, here are couple more thoughts for you

Example for string "hello"

- Ok: start = 0, end = 5 => i = 0, range.length = 5 and range.miniscule[i] is inside range
- Err: start = -1, end = 0  => i = -1, range.length = 1 but range.miniscule[i] is out of range for -1
- Err: start = 4, end = 5 => i = 4,
  range.length = 1 but range.miniscule[i] is out of range
- Err: start = 0, end = 7 => i = 0, this.miniscule[i] would fail for 5 and 6

Comment: yes, i haven't handled those exceptions yet, but im working on them!